# React.js Module parse failed:

Tags: reactjs, webpack, module

I don't understand why I got an error like this I am kind of a beginner so please could anyone help me solve this and tell me why it gives me an error

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
| registerServiceWorker();
|
```

This is my webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.export = {

    entry: '.src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
    ]
}
```

this is my index.js

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: i have tried add under loader: 'babel-loader' an query: { presets: [es2015] but then i got another bunch of errors

Comment: Whatever `registerServiceWorker` is, it's a file type that you aren't using a loader for. Can you include the contents of it in your question?

Comment: @Adam you mean like my index.js ?

Comment: What extension do your React files have?

Comment: @Adam they all use .js but i updated every package of webpack and babel. I removed all line between module.export = { -->>     module: { and added .babelrc now i didnt get same error i think i solve this error i posted but got another error with SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: You need `css-loader` to load your CSS file.

Comment: @Adam but it still there the error

Comment: What extension does your `registerServiceWorker` file have?